# Change button color when clicked (multiple clicks/colors)

Tags: c#, button, colors

I am trying to make a array of 8x8 buttons, and so far it works.
Now I have stumbled upon a problem.
I want the color of the button (backcolor) to change when it is clicked. And change to a different color when clicked again.

This is my code so far:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Button[,] btn = new Button[8,8];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int x = 0; x < btn.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < btn.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    btn[x,y] = new Button();
                    btn[x,y].SetBounds(40 * x, 40 * y, 40, 40);
                    btn[x,y].Click += new EventHandler(this.btnEvent_click);
                    Controls.Add(btn[x, y]);
                    btn[x,y].BackColor = Color.Black;
                }
            }

            /* 
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnEvent_click);
            btn[x,y].Text = Convert.ToString(x+","+y);
            Controls.Add(btn);
            btn[x,y].Click += new EventHandler(this.btnEvent_click);
            */
        }

        private void form1_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        void btnEvent_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           (Control)sender).BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

So far I can only change the color to red, and I've tried multiple if and for statements to change the color a second time.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you show the code of these if/for statements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi Temporary you can use below solution:

```
void btnEvent_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control ctrl = ((Control)sender);
    switch (ctrl.BackColor.Name)
    {
        case "Red":
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            break;
        case "Black":
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.White;
            break;
        case "White":
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
            break;
        case "Yellow":
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Purple;
            break;
        default:
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
            break;
    }
}
```

I know there can be a better solution also, but meanwhile you can go with this...you can add more colors also in switch statment as required

Comment: Thanks, it worked!
Do you have a idea on how i can like click some buttons and change the colors.
And then it remembers the colors of the buttons (like a save file)
I need it to configure my led cube

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question, can you please explain it more in detail

Comment: Well if i run the program and click some buttons (so some of them are green, others are red). I need to "save" that layout.

Comment: hey someone has answered it in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815874/how-to-get-control-properties-then-save-them-to-xml-and-load-it-back) artical

Answer (score 2):

You can make a new class, tha inherit from Button and handle internally the color change, something like this:

```
class TwoColorButton : Button
{
    private int stateCounter = 0;
    private Color[] states = new Color[] { Color.Black, Color.Red };

    public TwoColorButton()
        : base()
    {
        this.BackColor = states[stateCounter];
        this.Click += this.clickHandler;
    }

    protected void clickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stateCounter = stateCounter == 0 ? 1 : 0;
        this.BackColor = states[stateCounter];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Color.FromArgb(int) method and Random class. See below:

```
Random rnd = new Random();

//Alpha set allways 255
Color.FromArgb(255, rnd.Next(255), rnd.Next(255), rnd.Next(255));

//Or Completly random
Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next());
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something similar to?

```
    void btnEvent_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
       if ((Control)sender).BackColor != Color.Red)
           (Control)sender).BackColor = Color.Red;
       else 
           (Control)sender).BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it.. its working...

Inside the button1 click event:

```
Random randomGen = new Random();
KnownColor[] names = (KnownColor[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));
KnownColor randomColorName = names[randomGen.Next(names.Length)];
Color randomColor = Color.FromKnownColor(randomColorName);
button1.BackColor = randomColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can allways make a class that inherits the button class then add a counter to it for instance how often it was clicked and then inclrease that on every click and then change the color according to that click

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this if you want to "cycle" through a fixed set of colors:

```
void btnEvent_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    switch(button.BackColor)
    {
        case Color.Black: { button.BackColor= Color.Red;} break;
        case Color.Red: { button.BackColor= Color.Blue;} break;
        case Color.Blue: { button.BackColor= Color.Green;} break;
        // and so on ... don't forget the default clause, just in case
        default: { button.BackColor= Color.Black;} break;
    }
}
```